# argparse returns nested value for only 1 namespace

Tags: argparse

I am trying to get multiple namespaces for the following .py file which is executed on a remote server:

```
cmd = 'ssh root@{0} 2>/dev/null "/root/abc.py  {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8}"'.format(hostname, from_vm, to_vm, from_slot, to_slot, from_port, to_port, from_vm_inst, to_vm_inst)
```

Except hostname, all other entities are lists.

In abc.py, I have the following code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(nargs='+', dest='from_vm',
                    help='list of name of source VMs')
print("List of items: {}".format(args.from_vm))
```

This returns me the following:

> List of items: ['[myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r1-1]', '[myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-spt]', '[1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1]', '[1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1]', '[2,', '3,', '1,', '1,', '5,', '2,', '4,', '4]', '[3,', '6,', '1,', '3,', '6,', '4,', '5,', '2]', '[instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bc]', '[instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000c0]']

There is only 1 namespace associated with this:

> Namespace(from_vm=['[myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r1-1]', '[myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-r1-1,', 'myvm-spt,', 'myvm-r2-1,', 'myvm-spt]', '[1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1]', '[1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1,', '1]', '[2,', '3,', '1,', '1,', '5,', '2,', '4,', '4]', '[3,', '6,', '1,', '3,', '6,', '4,', '5,', '2]', '[instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bc]', '[instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000bc,', 'instance-000000c0,', 'instance-000000bf,', 'instance-000000c0]'])

This appears to me as a nested list. I want to have different namespaces for each and every list inside this nested list, but no success. I have tried using separate parser.add_argument with separate dest=xyz, but no success. Could someone please help? My requirement is to have have different namespace for each and every list.

Comment: DId you omit a `args = parser.parse_args()` command from your code sample?

Comment: @hpaulj, I have it in my code, its just that I did not mention it in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

`args = parser.parse_args()` returns an `argparse.Namespace` object.  In your case it produces an object with one attribute, `args.from_vm`.

`from_vm` is an attribute of the one Namespace object.  I don't think you want multiple 'namespaces' but rather a list of sublists, or may be multiple attributes, each with its own list of strings.

That attribute is a list of 64 strings.  The first element is `'[myvm-r1-1,', which looks like the start of a nested list, but isn't.  It is just a string.

Look at `sys.argv`.  The parser works with the list of strings in `sys.argv[1:]`.  That list is determined by the shell and python interpreter.

With `nargs='+'`, the parser just stores that whole list to the `from_vm` attribute - as is, without changes.

If you don't like what's in `sys.argv[1:]`, try adding quotes in the commandline.  Done right that will pass the whole thing in as one string, which you can then parse in your own way.  `JSON` has been used to handle general strings that look like nested lists and/or dictionaries.

Another option is to write that list like output to a file, and read and parse that separately.  Passing it through the commandline and argparse probably isn't worth the effort.  Use those for simple inputs like the file name.

I did a `' '.join(args.from_vm)` on a copy-n-paste of your post, and got

```
In [123]: txt=' '.join(_)
In [124]: txt
Out[124]: '[myvm-r1-1, myvm-r1-1, myvm-r2-1, myvm-r1-1, myvm-r1-1, myvm-r2-1, myvm-r2-1, myvm-r1-1] [myvm-r2-1, ...instance-000000c0]'
```

That's not going to be an easy parse even if you can load it as one string.

It would be a lot easier to parse if you could format your input string like

```
--arg1 myvm-r1-1 myvm-r1-1 myvm-r2-1 myvm-r1-1 myvm-r1-1 myvm-r2-1 myvm-r2-1 myvm-r1-1
--arg2 myvm-r2-1 myvm-r2-1 myvm-spt myvm-spt myvm-r1-1 myvm-spt myvm-r2-1 myvm-spt
--arg3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
--arg4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

That is, instead of a list of lists with `,` separate terms; separate the lists with flags, and omit the `[],`.

Comment: I used sys.argv[1:] and then used ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) which produced a string after removing the quotes. I have then used,   slash[(.*?)slash]     pattern match to delimit the square braces. I have then used split(",") to this matched pattern to convert it back into list. That served my purpose. Thank you hpaulj for the help.